# How to split number series in equal size chunks and save in a list in r

Tags: r, list, function, split, divide

I'm new to R.
I am trying to separate a series of number into equal-sized chunks, 
for example, 
X <- 123456798123 it has 12 characters in it.
Now I want to divide/split them into 6 character size chunks like [123456],[789123] and then save them into a list like separate elements like [1] "123456", [2] "789123", I want to do this for any length number which is divisible by 6. can anyone guide me to a function that can do this or other way. Thanks a lot.

Number is like 977787977970977972978076978676978831981132981883983671984264985265985806986064986346986909987749988622988959989165990746991001992535992747993482993506994293994873996102997740998210998458998781999295999464999529.

Answer (score 3):

Try this. Change the number within the curly braces to the length you desire. Be aware the last piece might be shorter than the required length.

```
strsplit('012345678910232122', perl = TRUE, "(?<=\\d{6})")
# [[1]]
# [1] "012345" "678910" "2321"
```

To make sure the string length is divisible by 6, you could use this check beforehand.

```
string <- "aaaaaa"
if (!(nchar(string) %% 6)) {
  stop("String length is not divisible by 6!")
}
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): String length is not divisible by 6!

# If you need to return a vector of strings which are divisible by 6
strings <- c("aaaaaa", "bbbbbbb")
sapply(strings, function(x) nchar(x) %% 6 == 0, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
#> [1] TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input is a string, i.e.:

```
s <- "977787977970977972978076978676978831981132981883983671984264985265985806986064986346986909987749988622988959989165990746991001992535992747993482993506994293994873996102997740998210998458998781999295999464999529"
```

- ***Solution 1***: you can use `substr` code to divide the string into chunks of size 6

```
lapply(seq(nchar(s)/6), function(k) substr(s,6*(k-1)+1,6*k))
```

- ***Solution 2***: you can make a matrix to formulate chunks

```
Map(intToUtf8,data.frame(matrix(utf8ToInt(s),nrow = 6)))
```

and its **efficient** version is

```
apply(matrix(utf8ToInt(s),nrow = 6),2,intToUtf8)
```

Comment: Thanks for comments @IceCreamToucan! I will update your feedback to my solution 2

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution (returns a vector not a list):

```
n = 6

split_positions <- which(1:nchar(X) %% n == 0)

# As vector: 

sapply(split_positions, function(y){paste(unlist(strsplit(X, ""))[y:(y+(n-1))], collapse = "")})

# As list: 

lapply(split_positions, function(y){paste(unlist(strsplit(X, ""))[y:(y+(n-1))], collapse = "")})
```

Data:

```
X <- "977787977970977972978076978676978831981132981883983671984264985265985806986064986346986909987749988622988959989165990746991001992535992747993482993506994293994873996102997740998210998458998781999295999464999529"
```

Comment: The number is like, 977787977970977972978076978676978831981132981883983671984264985265985806986064986346986909987749988622988959989165990746991001992535992747993482993506994293994873996102997740998210998458998781999295999464999529 this long or more.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using `substring`

```
get_split_vec <- function(X) {
    n <- round(nchar(X)/2)
    list(substring(X, 1, n), substring(X, n+1))
}

get_split_vec(123456798123)

#[[1]]
#[1] "123456"

#[[2]]
#[1] "798123"
```

Comment: 977787977970977972978076978676978831981132981883983671984264985265985806986064986346986909987749988622988959989165990746991001992535992747993482993506994293994873996102997740998210998458998781999295999464999529 Not working for numbers like this long.

Comment: @WaqasAhmed It works but output is not formatted correctly. Pass it as string instead `get_split_vec("977787977970977972978076978676978831981132981883983671984264985265985806986064986346986909987749988622988959989165990746991001992535992747993482993506994293994873996102997740998210998458998781999295999464999529")`